# How do I put a time stamp with: wget --output-file=[FILENAME] [URL]

Tags: shell, date, wget

So I've been trying to put a timestamp on some images I'm downloading from a webcam, but so far it's been saving the images with the names camera3_date'

here's my line that I enter:

```
wget --output-document=camera_3‘date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S’.jpg [IP]/image.jpg
```

and then it downloads like such:

```
--2014-11-25 11:10:28--  [Couldn't Add this FTP link].jpg
           => “camera3_‘date”
Resolving +%y-%m-%d_%h... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address “+%y-%m-%d_%h”
--2014-11-25 11:10:28--  [http link .jpg not allowed]
Connecting to [IP]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 447143 (437K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: “camera3_‘date”

100%[======================================>] 447,143      486K/s   in 0.9s

2014-11-25 11:10:29 (486 KB/s) - “camera3_‘date” saved [447143/447143]

FINISHED --2014-11-25 11:10:29--
Downloaded: 1 files, 437K in 0.9s (486 KB/s)
```

So I'm getting the image I want but I can't save the timestamp correctly, how should I fix this?

Comment: `wget -o "camera_3$(date +%F_%T).jpg" [IP]/image.jpg`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use backticks (`` ` ``) instead of fancy quotes (`‘`).

```
wget --output-document=camera_3`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`.jpg [IP]/image.jpg
```

Or better yet use the sub command notation, `$(...)`.

```
wget --output-document=camera_3$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S).jpg [IP]/image.jpg
```

Additionally you can simply the formatting to `date` like so:

```
wget --output-document=camera_3$(date +%F_%T).jpg [IP]/image.jpg
```

The date macros `%F` and `%T` are shorthand for the `%Y-%m-%d` and `%H:%M:%S` formats.

Comment: @BradFlynn - please remember to mark this as the accepted answer so other's know your issues' been resolved.